# How can I bypass internal protection of a Swift package to add CustomDebugStringConvertible conformance?

Tags: swift

I'm wanting to add `CustomDebugStringConvertible` conformance to a class in order to view some information from a private property on a swift package class with `internal` protection. I'm not able to add this conformance due to the internal protection. Is there any way to bypass this protection for the sake of temporary debugging? Maybe some `@unsafeXXX` compiler flag?

Longer description for why:

I am having some sort of KVO retain cycle in my app. It's likely something wrong in my own code, but the way it manifests itself in the memory graph UI is via a "swift closure context" of some package code. This particular package handles UserDefaults, so trying to track down the retain cycle by looking at the code alone would be a nightmare, as it's used in countless places for many keys. The memory graph's "print description" output is useless to me as it just displays a class name and memory location. However one of the package's classes that's linked in the memory graph does hold a private property that is the key name of that default. My thinking is if I can add conformance for `CustomDebugStringConvertible` to that class, I can at least see what key the problem is with, which greatly narrows the search area.

The other alternative is to delete the package from the project and add it manually from source code, but that seems a clunky way to read a single private property for debugging purposes.

Comment: Did you try `dump(whatever)`?